# javascript variable corresponds to DOM element with the same ID

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new to javascript, and I just noticed a javascript behavior that I haven't seen documented anywhere. If I have a DOM element with an assigned id, say "x", then in my javascript, that element is automatically assigned to variable x. I see this in chrome and safari. Is this a documented feature of javascript?

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id='x'>
<input type='text' name='info' id='info'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Complete'/>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = function() {
    alert( x==document.getElementById('x') );
    info.value = 'Test me!';
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When loaded, it will alert true, and the input area will show 'Test me!'. If this is the right behavior, why do we need document.getElementById at all?

Comment: WOW! I've been coding JavaScript for **years** and I've never ever known about this! I actually found this answer because I was trying to find a way to simplify getting references to UI elements in JavaScript instead of having redundancy all over the place...

Answer (score 13):

This behavior is documented in [the HTML standard (chapter 6.2.4)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object).

The standard defines "named elements" which are HTML elements that have either a `name` or `id` attribute set. (Note that the `name` attribute is only defined on certain types of HTML elements.)

For each named element, the browser (environment) defines a corresponding global property.

Comment: As of my comment, Chrome and Firefox implement this behavior but IE11 does not. I must confess I didn't even know about this feature until now.

Comment: So that's the purpose of `window` being a global variable...

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="w"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        alert( w );

        w = null;

        alert( w );

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this test in IE8. You will figure out that w is global and cannot be overwritten.
Change "w = null" in "var w = null" and reload (after emptying cache)...

IE8 checks for variables before runtime and removes the global correspondent.
I really can't await the day when web developers don't have to support IE8 any more...

HINT: don't use variable names equal to DOM element id's.. OMG OMG

Answer (score -3):

This is an IE-only non-standard feature.

Do not rely on it.

Comment: Oh no! Horrible feature! I hope this is an April Fools' Day joke.

Comment: It's not non-standard: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#dom-window-nameditem See the bullet: *"HTML elements that have an id content attribute whose value is name."*

Comment: This is *not* IE-only, try it in other browsers using http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/ghY99/.

Comment: This behavior is present in IE9, Chrome, Opera and Safari. Only Firefox 4 does not implement this. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/WbwEC/

Comment: @Marcel It's real. Fortunately, existing global properties cannot be replaced - if you have this `<div id="document">`, then `document` will still point to the `document` object, and not the DIV.