# How to force Chrome (or any other WebKit browser) not to use "default" tag names?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, cross-browser, google-chrome-devtools

I was having issues because of Chrome automatically referencing DIV... It works that way in Safari (desktop and mobile), but not in Firefox.

See image:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools vs Firebug]

See Fiddle (open in Chrome, then in Firefox):
http://jsfiddle.net/stefek99/Sqcff/

The question is - **how to disable this feature**? I would really like to develop in "strict" mode without any Google quirks, just to make sure my code is cross-browser compliant.

Comment: Fixed. Sometimes I would like to refer to a variable, not a *div* - this ambiguity is bug prone...

Answer (score 1):

This is a known 'problem', however I have not been able to find a reliable method of disabling this. One might think that `"use strict";` should probably disable it but that doesn't seem to be the case.

In any case, some more explanation on it; [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here) As explained there it [will probably be standardized in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#named-access-on-the-window-object). It all started out as a [non-standard IE feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515659/javascript-variable-corresponds-to-dom-element-with-the-same-id), which ofcourse got mimicked in other browsers. Theres even a msdn [blog post noting it as a 'problem'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2009/10/22/internet-explorer-creates-global-variables-for-each-object-in-the-dom.aspx) so it seems a bit silly the HTML5 working group is trying to standardize it now.

I would like to note to anybody to please not rely on this problem feature as it is very ambiguous and hard to debug for programmers who don't know of it.