# Internet Explorer weirdness - function item() { [native code] } - what does it do?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

### See image:

[image]

Similar question on Microsoft website: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785194/function-item-native-code

Tried Google.com, Facebook, StackOverflow - every website I visit has this weird feature. Fire up your IE9 (haven't tested other versions) and type `item` in you development console.

If I haven't tried other websites I would think that there is a `<div id="item">` see also:

- [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)
- [How to force Chrome (or any other WebKit browser) not to use "default" tag names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798976/how-to-force-chrome-or-any-other-webkit-browser-not-to-use-default-tag-names) *(this is my question asking how to stop it)*

So on this occasion the question is - why `function item()` is present on so many websites when IE is used?

---

UPDATE: super simplified test case.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It's a function on the `window` object.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Internet Explorer. It's not part of the *websites*, in other words, it's part of the *browser*.

It's from the HTMLCollection interface, part of the DOM spec. Internet Explorer seems to consider the `window` object to be a collection.

Comment: Quick and easy! I was doomed by not using ```var``` in the following statement ```for (item in basket.items)``` (lesson learnt)

Comment: OMG microsoft is so stupid, sigh.  Year after year.  The hair-loss of developers is criminal...

Comment: @MichalStefanow: I just had a similar problem with `close` and couldn't figure out what was happening. Thanks!