# JavaScript undefined variables are auto-defined?

Tags: javascript

Is it true that JavaScript automatically attempts to define undefined variables to:

```
document.getElementById('someUndefVarName')
```

As in, the following appear to be equivalent:

```
<div id="myUndefVar">:)</div>
<script>
    alert(myUndefVar); // why does this work!?
    alert(document.getElementById('myUndefVar'));
</script>
```

See JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/AH35k/1/

Or is something else happening that I don't understand? This really caught me off-guard as I expected some sort of error since I'm using "use strict".

Comment: See the JSFiddle code, the variable is clearly NOT explicitly defined anywhere.

Comment: Yes.  Browsers will create global variable from element IDs.  I wouldn't rely on this behavior, though.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6381766

Comment: Browsers create global bindings (`window` properties) for element "id" values.

Comment: If you wanna get the error, then move the `<div>` tag after the `<script>` .. you'll get the undefined error!

Comment: @Pointy that seems crazy...so an id="jQuery" would override the jquery object on window. Is that normal behaviour? and does "use strict" change that?

Comment: This isn't a "JS" thing.  This is a browser-vendor, DOM-extension, into the JS scope. If you did this using variables which are not DOM extensions, you'd have different results. I believe the initial intent "once upon a time" was form-handling from `window`, by default.

Comment: This seems like something that should have been mentioned in "The Good Parts" as an anti-pattern.

Comment: @theporchrat: Let's find out: http://jsfiddle.net/AH35k/3/ :-D

Comment: @theporchrat Personally I think it's a really terrible idea. Internet Explorer did it a long time ago, and eventually the other browsers capitulated.

Comment: @mikhail "The Good Parts" typically avoids most DOM stuff (other than to mention it's a horrible, horrible API, which needs to burn), and sticks to the actual language.  For instance, this doesn't actually happen in NodeJS, or other embedded JS, elsewhere.

Comment: @RocketHazmat well at least it seems to not override it is it already exists, phew. THIS just seems like a horrible "feature" i wonder what the historical significance of it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some (and only *some*) browsers create global vars from IDs.

This can be useful when debugging (ie in the chrome console you can just type "Blah" to access an HTML Element with `id="Blah"`), but **should not be relied on to work cross-browser**.

Further, if you do this:

```
<div id="myUndefVar">:)</div>
<script>
    var myUndefVar;
    alert(myUndefVar);
</script>
```

Or this:

```
<div id="myUndefVar">:)</div>
<script>
    alert(myUndefVar);
    var myUndefVar;
</script>
```

Then the `alert` will display the value `undefined`. It will only lookup the named IDs of elements if there is no other var defined in the same scope with the same name (including hoisting, as in the second example).

Comment: Example of a browser that doesn't : Firefox in standards mode.

Comment: The var trick above doesn't work in Safari. I just got caught out by it. You have to explicitly assign something to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer to this question is well summed up as:

**Browsers automatically create global variables from element IDs**

A related question: [javascript variable corresponds to DOM element with the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515659/javascript-variable-corresponds-to-dom-element-with-the-same-id)

This seems like a pretty bad feature, I would avoid relying on this behavior.