# Javascript: access DOM elements without getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

Below is some sample code.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="access">
        <form id="test">
            <input id="password"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>  
    </div>
    <script>
        console.log(password);
        alert(wrapper.className);
    </script>
</body>
```

The console log returns the DOM element with id `password`. The alert is "alert".

It works in normal code as well, e.g. `var x = wrapper.className;`

Surely this is not right? What is the point of `document.getElementById`, `$('#password')` or `goog.dom.getElement` if it just works like this? Are these functions just for legacy now?

It works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, incidentally.

Comment: Some browsers define elements with IDs as global variables. IMO, use `getElementById`.

Comment: You can thank IE for that. They started it, others followed for compatibility. It's considered bad practice. Stick with `document.getElementById` or the equivalent in the libraries for which you provided examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript undefined variables are auto-defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340666/javascript-undefined-variables-are-auto-defined), also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767961/are-ids-for-an-html-element-always-available-from-the-window-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here

Comment: @DavidThomas It may be a duplicate, but you need to know the answer to find it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer should give you a lot to go on:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6381766/944006

You shouldn't use these variables, and you DEFINITELY don't want to depend on them working correctly across browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Backwards compatibility is the reason IDs are mapped to properties of the `window`.

It's also a major reason to avoid global variables - in fact some browsers will outright break if you try to use a global variable that's the same name as an element's ID.